# python. заголовок xml . как добавить заголовок <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>?

Tags: python-3.x

```
parts = xml.Element("parts")   
for respons in response[1:]:
    part = xml.SubElement(parts, "part")
    xml.SubElement(part, "id").text = str(respons[2])       
    parts.append(part)
tree = xml.ElementTree(parts)
tree.write(filename, encoding="utf-8")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `write()` метод `xml_declaration=True` передайте.

Comment: всю голову разворотило, спасибо